# How to change (add or remove) class inside of <ul> childs when childs are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making simple app, basically I'm learning Web technologies as JavaScript, jQuery, HTMl and so on.. So I've created simple dashboard and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see guys, when I click on a category, arrow which is pointing down should point up when category is clicked, and I saw that's about this class:

```
fa-angle-down
```

So basically when category is clicked I should remove a class and add a new class called:

```
fa-angle-up
```

But I don't know how to achieve this by writing code once and applying it to all elements on page that behave like this, please any kind of help would be awesome with some explanation why is that like that..

Here is my HTML:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-1"><i class="far fa-clipboard"></i> <span class="menu-item-text">TEST</span><i class="fas fa-angle-down fa-fw pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul id="submenu-1" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-2"><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i> <span class="menu-item-text">TEST 2</span><i class="fas fa-angle-down fa-fw pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul id="submenu-2" class="collapse">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="investigaciones/favoritas"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="menu-item-text">TEST 3</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="sugerencias"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> <span class="menu-item-text">TEST 4</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>

</nav>
```

```
   <script>
        $('#submenu-1 > ul > li').on('click',function(event){alert('Does this trigger?');});
    </script>
```

And as you can see guys there is lil bit of javaScript code:

```
 <script>
        $('#submenu-1 > ul > li').on('click',function(event){alert('Does this trigger?');});
    </script>
```

As it's possible to notice I've tried to attach and event handler to an `li` that is part of `ul` that is located in element with id of `#submenu-1`

But unfortunatelly this not works :(

Comment: you can add click to the ul right?

Comment: I highly recommend you don't base your jQuery's off element names (ul li etc).  Take a moment and read [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, I would highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

First change your html with some `js-*` class tags then some simple jquery.  You can ignore the styles, those are just for the example.

`js-angles` is the container where only a single element can be *up*.  `js-angle` is the element that contains 1 or more items that need to change from down to up when it (`js-angle`) is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.js-angles .js-angle').on('click', 
    // This is an arrow function so there is no "this"
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
    // we can easily replace "this" with "e.currentTarget" 
    // https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
    (e) => {
    var $this = $(e.currentTarget);
    // $container "contains" everything we want to track/change
    var $container = $this.closest('.js-angles');
    // find anything in the container that currently has up and toggle it with down
    $container.find('.fa-angle-up').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down'); 
    // find the down within the element we clicked and toggle up/down
    $this.find('.fa-angle-down').toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');  
  });
});
```

```css
a { text-docoration: none }
li { width: 120px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav js-angles">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-1" class="js-angle">
      <i class="far fa fa-clipboard"></i>
      <span class="menu-item-text">TEST</span>
      <i class="fas fa fa-angle-down fa-fw pull-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul id="submenu-1" class="collapse">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 1.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu-2" class="js-angle">
      <i class="far fa fa-folder-open"></i>
      <span class="menu-item-text">TEST 2</span>
      <i class="fas fa fa-angle-down fa-fw pull-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul id="submenu-2" class="collapse">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 2.1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 2.2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> SUBMENU 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you added js-angle to each of link so you could write javaScript method once and use it on all elements with that class, I understand this well ? After that you stored element who triggerent event in variable $this, and you found his sibling (something like that) and you added class down to the sibling, well could you please comment line by line in that method?

Comment: Yes I can do that for you! :D

Answer (score -1):

Use .toggleClass().

```
<i id="arrow" class="fa fa-angle-down" style="margin-left:40px"></i>

<script>
  $('.navbar-nav li').click(function(){
    $("#arrow", this).toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
  });
</script>
```

I have attached a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pouu7daw/ .
hope it helps

Comment: No reason to use find.  Just `$('.navbar-nav > li')` would produce the same results with less code.